# Nginx - Allow access to folder directory only by referring URL

Tags: nginx, permissions, file-permissions, hotlinking

front-end web developer here. Sorry in advance.

My company wants to store new builds of our software on our web server, running Nginx, provided by [WP Engine](http://wpengine.com).

The file path for these builds would be `company.com/downloads/file.zip`. **We want to restrict access to files in this folder unless they come from a specific referring URL that sits behind a login gate for our customers.**

- If user clicks link to any file inside `/downloads/` from allowed referrer, user gets file
- If user clicks link from any other source, return 404 or redirect to homepage
- If empty referrer or direct access attempt, return 404 or redirect to homepage

I've found a resource on preventing hotlinking for images (we'll be dealing with .zip files), which might work for me, but I need help with the syntax of this language. There's probably a bunch wrong with it.

```
location ~ /downloads/$ {
valid_referers none blocked ~.allowed_domain.com;
if ($invalid_referer) {
return 404;
}
}
```

WP Engine doesn't allow me to add Nginx code myself, so I'll have to send them the code I want them to implement. If anyone knows how to do this and can help me out, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Why? There are already WordPress plugins to handle hotlink protection. Getting into nginx config for this seems excessive.

Comment: I've looked for plugins, but found very few which were all poorly reviewed. But I did find this one, which might work: https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-security-and-firewall/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other possibility is to use [X-Accel](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/x-accel/) header. I don't know your use case, so it may not be a good fit.

*X-Accel* is nginx specific header. You can issue that header in your PHP script - like `header("X-Accel-Redirect: /private-downloads/magic.iso")`  When nginx recognize this header, it will server content of the file `magic.iso` located in `/data/private-downloads`.

So your task is to prepare `download.php` which check authorization and respond either with *X-Accel* header or redirect to login screen.

Definition of `/private-downloads/` in nginx.conf

```
location /private-downloads/ {
    internal;    # this
    alias /data/private-downloads;
    # this should be located outside of HTTP server root
}
```

For more details, plase check x-accel questions on serverfault. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189758/serve-large-file-with-php-and-nginx-x-accel-redirect)

Comment: Oh, does this solution require me to be able to put a directory outside of `public_html`? Because WP Engine won't let me do that, which is super frustrating.

Comment: You can put the secret directory inside `public_html` but it is not recommended technique. At least, try to use subdirectory name which is hard to guess.

Comment: Gotcha. And do I need to add that Nginx code you included in this answer as well? Or is that just additional info?

Comment: If you don't use internal alias, you may not omit  `location` internal statement. But I'm not sure on this area. I would stick with  `/private-downloads/` internal alias pointing to HTML root. It can save you some work later. (e.g. if you move to another hosting, name of your secret sudirectory will be exposed, ...)

Comment: There is a big typo in previous comment. There should be **You probably may omit**

Comment: My company ended up finding another solution that didn't require use of our Nginx server. But I did all the reading you linked me to, and I can clearly see that you gave me the right answer that would have worked had I been able to implement it. Thank you for you help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `valid_referers` nginx directive. ( [nginx doc](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_referer_module.html) )

```
location /downloads/ {
    alias /var/www/downloads;
    valid_referers  www.example.me ;

if ($invalid_referer) {
        return 404;
    }
}
```

I personally never tried this in production, because I prefer to use [X-Accel header](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/x-accel/) . You can verify your user in PHP script and then send  nginx header X-accel. The header will ask nginx to server the static files by nginx.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll definitely shoot this over to them and give it a shot on a staging server. How can I use X-Accel header? Sorry, probably a stupid question, but if it's a better solution and a valid option for me, I'd like that.

Comment: I've been doing a lot of reading on this, and I can't figure out why this answer didn't work. Granted, I had WP Engine implement it for me so I can't verify that it was done correctly. In your other answer, you mentioned that I can X-Accel through PHP? That might be the best option for me. I'll give that a shot.