# Nginx - allow access to directory

Tags: nginx, permissions, .htaccess

I have a WordPress site on a LAMP server (CentOS 7).
In the WordPress root folder I added a folder called `minisite`.

```
www.example.com/minisite/file.html
```

While trying to access the `minisite` directory from the browser I get a 403 error.

How can I allow the access to the `minisite` directory?

I read the following question but the answer wasn't very clear to me.
Also, I couldn't figure out in what file the changes are made. 
[Nginx - Allow access to folder directory only by referring URL](https://serverfault.com/questions/834252/nginx-allow-access-to-folder-directory-only-by-referring-url)

Comment: Are you literally trying to access the bare directory, eg. `/minisite/` (as stated), or a file in that directory, eg. `/minisite/file.html`, as in your example URL?

Comment: Please provide `nginx` config.

Comment: I try to access the  `/minisite/file.html` file only. In which file can I find the `nginx` configuration? I found this link but I dont know where to add the code  http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_autoindex_module.html.

Comment: O.K, I found the configuration file at the `/etc/nginx/conf.d`directory. I added this block to the file :      `location /minisite/ {
    autoindex on;
    }` now I can access the directory but I see a list of files in it.  how can I auto load the index.html file that is in the `minisite` directory

Answer (score 2):

O.k first I had to find the configuration file. 
I found it in the `/etc/nginx/conf.d` directory.

Than I cane across this tutorial: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_autoindex_module.html

I added this block inside the `server` block:

```
location /srita/ {
index index.html;
autoindex on;
}
```